# CSS center an element

Tags: css

Why do 'margin left and right set to auto and max. and min. width' center an element?

```
#header{
    max-width: 1400px;
    min-width: 360px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I do not get it.

Comment: That's how css works.

Comment: So, there is no logic on it, just learn it by heart.

Comment: Well, the browser sees that you have no preference (`auto`), and therefore just puts it in the middle.

There is logic to it. Read more at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Answer (score 1):

It divides the sum of the empty space on the right and left sides of an element by two and uses that as **`margin-left`** and **`margin-right`**, thus centering it. Another way of thinking about it is subtracting the width of the child from the width of the parent and then dividing that by 2.

In reality, **`margin-left`** and **`margin-right`** are still set to **`auto`**, so if you try to get their values in JavaScript, you are going to get **`"auto"`**, but that is the logic behind it.

**The math behind it is:**

```
marginLeft = (parentWidth - childWidth) / 2
marginRight = marginLeft
```

Comment: You're welcome @Cubancoffee. I hope it helped you understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since `auto` in both right and left margins take up the "available" space equally, the element is aligned to the center.

A left or right margin with auto will take up all of the "available" space making the element look like it has been flushed right or left.

Look in this [source](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-margin-auto/) for more information.

You can easily understand with the following demo:

```css
div{
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
auto
</div>
```

In the above snippet, you can see when you use margin-left auto the div is taking up all the available space so it pushed to right. Now, you can think by using `margin-right:auto;` will push the element towards the left. So, using both will force it to stay at center by taking up both available space.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not satisfied with the exhaustiveness of the other answers, here's a more detailed explanation. In general, the [w3c Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) elaborates on this in great detail and should be consulted for questions requiring a more precise answer.

---

The typical use case `margin: 0 auto` (top and bottom set to 0, left and right to auto) works by having **the browser calculate the available space and apply it to each `auto` value of a property, divided equally**.

In the attempt to also provide a "math behind it" example (I put this in quotes, as it's a very simplified visualisation of the actual math) is much closer to this:

```
availableSpace = (parentWidth - childWidth)
marginLeft, marginRight = availableSpace / amountOfAutoValues
```

This will work under the following conditions (simplified):

- it's not `absolute`- or `fixed`-positioned
- it's not floating
- it's not an `inline` element (This is to be distinguished from "it must be a `block` element", which is wrong - for example, `inline-block` won't work)

This is, because those modes already overwrite the object's place within the document, and calculating a margin is likely not advantageous.

---

The only requirement is just the margin setting for it to technically apply - you only need to set a `width` (or `max-width`) smaller than the parent in order to *see* the effect, as in any other scenario, the available space will simply be `0`.
`min-width` will never have any effect regarding automatic margins in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same result if instead of `max-width` and `min-width` you used `display:table` along with the `margin` + `auto` value and rest of the code. If left only with `margin-left` it will align to the extreme right corner of the page, if left only with `margin-right` it will align to the extreme left, now what do you think will happen if you leave it with `margin-left margin-right`? I'm pretty sure you won't create a paradox. :)

```
-------------------------> margin-left:auto

margin-right:auto <------------------------

margin-left:auto <-------> margin-right:auto
```